# Reverse monty hall problem probability?

Tags: probability, monty-hall

So I understand the monty hall problem fine but not the reverse.

Premise of question: As I was watching a show on youtube there were 3 people eating burritos and one had a bad filling and one of the people had the option to switch with one of the other two people then all people bite the middle of the burrito.

What I think I understand: if the burritos are distributed at random you can assume a 66% of getting a good burrito. If you stay with your burrito you remain with a 66% chance. If you switch your odds will go down because the best you can do is the same fine burrito or you can get the bad burrito.

What I dont understand: What is your odds if the host doesnt eliminate one of the burritos? Is it the same 66% no matter what cause you dont know any additional information even if the options of switching are equal to or worse than your own hopefully good option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think your decision matters since no information is added by the elimination/non elimination of a burrito.

Consider the different strategies of switch/stay.
$$P(good_i) = 1-P_{bad,i}=2/3$$

If you go with switch:
$$P(good|good_i)= 1/2$$
$$P(good|bad_i)= 1$$
$$P(good) = \frac{2}{3}\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}=2/3$$

If you stay:
$$P(good|good_i)= 1$$
$$P(good|bad_i)= 0$$
$$P(good) = \frac{2}{3}+0=2/3$$

So it doesn't matter as expected

---

Edit:The question is extended to include additional question from asker:

> So if the host did reveal one of the good ones would switching make you ?
>   more likely to lose because it's the reverse of the monty hall with two 
>   goods and a bad. Or, once revealed that one good could have been a good, 
>   bad or a rhino for all it matters because it's already eliminated and 
>   it's the regular monty hall paradox and your chances increase by 
>   switching?

Say the host unwittingly revealed one of the good burritos. I believe you need to take into account the unwittingly part. Say you choose a burrito and the host is known to not know which burrito is which.

$$P(good_i|good_{revealed}) = \frac{P(good_{revealed}|good_i)}{P(good_{revealed})}P(good_i) = \frac{\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{2}{3}}\frac{2}{3}=1/2$$

If the host doesn't know then no information is transmitted and you are neither better off switching nor staying.

---

Say the host always reveals a good burrito, then we are in standard Monty hall territory. We should stay.

Comment: So if the host did reveal one of the good ones would switching make you more likely to lose because it's the reverse of the monty hall with two goods and a bad. Or, once revealed that one good could have been a good, bad or a rhino for all it matters because it's already eliminated and it's the regular monty hall paradox and your chances increase by switching?

Comment: Depends on host's knowledge/behavior. If they always reveal a good burrito then it's the reverse monty hall. If they reveal at random then it doesn't matter.

Comment: @Badatmath does this answer your question?

Comment: Yeah I think I understand somehow math makes the world far more and less magical and I'm not sure how I feel about it but I'm on board now

Comment: @Badatmath totally agree. I do love to explore and try to figure things out with math. :)